# Is there a valid alternative to ANTLR written in C#?

Tags: c#, antlr

ANTLR is a great piece of software, but, in my opinion, is a little bit uncomfortable for a C# programmer (the C# porting is out of date, the parser antlr-3.1.3.jar required java, etc)
I'm looking for a "more C#  native" language tool  in order to parse a simple json-like grammar, any suggestion?

Comment: personally I find it a great tool, especially with the antlrworks GUI which makes making the grammar much easier. The C# code generated is also pretty OK but maybe could be optimized a bit better.

Comment: Antlr now has a [Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Antlr) that installs as a simple dll reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[peg-sharp](https://github.com/dbremner/peg-sharp) (C# packrat parser) is a simple but valid alternative.

Comment: That does looks nice. I especially like the embedded custom error messages you can give your rules!

Answer (score 4):

I've used the GOLD Parser Generator, a freeware tool that you can use to specify BNF grammars, and then generate a parser in almost any target language including C#. You can also modify the way the parser generator generates C# code by altering a text template.

http://www.devincook.com/goldparser/

Comment: Link is broken, perhaps update with http://www.goldparser.org/ (assuming this is the same project)